# How do I send non-default Github webhook to SNS?

Tags: github, aws-lambda, webhooks, amazon-sns

Currently, I have followed [this tutorial](http://nerds.simacan.com/post/145155077317/using-serverless-aws-technology-aws-lamdba-sns) and set up Lambda, Github and my SNS for receiving responses from GitHub.

However, I am getting only the [default webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) through this setting.

**How do I customise it to work with one of the other [non-default events here](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), like a pull-request (other than just `push`)?**

Answer (score 1):

In GitHub (https://github.com///settings/hooks/new) click on the radio button under `Which events would you like to trigger this webhook?` and select `Send me everything.`